# Change button size in without disabling AutoLayout

Tags: ios, swift

```
 @IBAction func openURL(sender: UIButton) {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com")!)
    openURL.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 200)
    openURL.setTitleColor(UIColor.redColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    openURL.setTitleColor(UIColor.redColor(), forState: UIControlState.Highlighted)
}
```

I tried to change my button size, programatically or not, but it remains the same. The button seems to change view in Xcode, but not in my phone.

Can I change my button size without disabling AutoLayout ?

If it can't be done, can it be done manually via drag and drop? Without constraint is it good?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Add constraint for width and height**

[image]

**Drag outlets of the constraint to the viewcontroller subclass**

[image]

**Change the value of this constraint like so.**

[image]

This is also animatable

Comment: this works, thanks. i don't see that height part before

Comment: after setting the constant of the constraint is good to call the view.layoutIfNeeded.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting frames you should make property of your respective Constraint and set its constant according to your need

e.g
I have view which i need to have 0 height for some reason, I'll make height constraint property and set it's constant to 0